# Модальное окно с формой на fancybox

Tags: javascript

Поставил `fancybox`. На странице сайта есть форма, при сабмите которой должно всплывать окошко на `fancybox` с новой формой, причём необходимо передать данные введённые в первой форме, во вторую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный код `js` для осуществления этого. Начало такое:

```
$('#fast-order-form').submit(function() {
        jQuery.fancybox({
    .........
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fancybox API](http://fancybox.net/api)

Здесь есть описание events. Вам необходим event onStart. Следовательно код будет иметь вид.

```
$('#fast-order-form').submit(function() {
        jQuery.fancybox({
             onStart: function(){
                  //Здесь заполняете свою форму.
             }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Для того чтобы собрать данные с предыдущей формы воспользуйтесь функцией [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)